# Should it be "In chapters 1 or 2" or "In chapter 1 or 2"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

Consider the following example:

> In chapters 1 and 2, the author discusses X

In this example, *chapter* needs to be pluralized for the sentence to be grammatically correct, right? But what if *and* is replaced with *or* – do we still need the plural form? That is, which of the following is correct – (1) or (2)?

1. In chapter 1 or 2, the author discusses X
2. In chapters 1 or 2, the author discusses X

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know what chapter it was in, but it was in only one of them, use

> In chapter 1 or 2, the author...

I can't think of a reason to use your example 2.

Comment: Thank you! Thing is, to me it sounds odd saying *chapters 1 and 2* as well, because in my own language we don't use the plural form in that context, so I have a hard time determining whether the same goes for examples with *or*. But now I have my answer, so thanks! :)

Comment: I should add that in ordinary speech, people may say "in chapter 1 and 2...".

Comment: Really? Huh! Interesting :)